# Ansible: loop over list of dicts 3 levels deep in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I need to loop over a list of dicts that's 3 levels deep in my dictionary. Here's an example of my dictionary:

```yaml
orgs:
  - name: Org 1
    templates:
      - name: template 1
        nodes:
          - identifier: identifier 1
            secondary_template: some_template
          - identifier: identifier 2
            secondary_template: some_other_template
  - name: Org 2 (etc)
```

I need to have all 3 levels of vars in a single task. I've tried to do a set_fact first, but it's just grabbing the last template in the list. My single task needs to loop through all 3 levels of the dict; i.e., it needs the org name, the template name, & then needs to loop through each template's nodes, grabbing the identifier & secondary_template. Closest I've come is:

```
- debug:
    var: item.1.nodes | map(attribute='identifier')
  loop: "{{ orgs | subelements ('templates', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

But that spits out a list of the identifiers & not an individual value.

Comment: Not quite following you.  Perhaps a better example of what you want, with input and expected output, would help.

Comment: hey @Jack - sorry I wasn't more clear - please see Vladimir's answer below: it accomplishes what I was looking for. For future reference, though, what could I have done to better explain my issue?

Comment: As Vladimir posted the output of the play, your question should include the output you wanted to see.

Comment: Got it - thanks, will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to iterate *include_tasks*. For example, create a file

```yaml
shell> cat loop_nodes.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ outer_item.0.name }} -
          {{ outer_item.1.name }} -
          {{ item.identifier }} -
          {{ item.secondary_template }}"
  loop: "{{ outer_item.1.nodes }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ outer_item.1.name }}"
```

and include it in the loop

```yaml
    - include_tasks: loop_nodes.yml
      loop: "{{ orgs | subelements ('templates', skip_missing=True) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Org 1 - template 1 - identifier 1 - some_template
  msg: Org 1 - template 1 - identifier 2 - some_other_template
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir - this does exactly what I was looking for. I was nearly there on my own, using an include_tasks, but I didn't have it figured out to this end. Thanks again!